# Android run time permissions - onRequestPermissionsResult callback is not triggering in an activity

Tags: android, permissions, sms, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to send SMS using SmsManager. Below is my code, followed as per android documentation. But the problem is, it is not triggering the onRequestPermissionsResult call back after pressing DENY/ALLOW button on the permission window. I even added super.onRequestPermissionsResult based on somebody's suggestion in one of the post. I have tested with Log statements and in debug mode by setting breakpoints, but onRequestPermissionsResult is not at all getting called. Because of this, even after granting permission, the first SMS never goes out, "SMS sent. 1" is never displayed. What am I missing? In what scenarios callback is not triggered?

```
private void sendSMSMessage() {
        phoneNo = "+919535000000";
        message = "Test SMS message";

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(NewAppointment.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted. Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(NewAppointment.this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                Toast.makeText(NewAppointment.this,
                        "Send SMS permission is needed to send notifications.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // Request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NewAppointment.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
            message = "Test SMS message 2";
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent. 2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.i(TAG,"In onRequestPermissionsResult callback ---> ");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    message = "Test SMS message 1";
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent. 1",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Can you make sure that you are not using noHistory="true" in manifest for the activity ? If we use noHistory="true", we will not get callback.

Comment: It is not used in manifest file.

Comment: R u making this call inside Fragment or Activity? If it is inside fragment, then can you please try to override the onRequestPermissionsResult method in the attaching activity of the fragment?

Comment: It is inside an activity, not fragment.

Comment: your activity extends AppCompatActivity as well right?

Comment: Yes. Activity extends AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. The activity was getting killed even before onRequestPermissionsResult was triggered. Made changes to the code so that activity was not killed.